# Preserving formatting in attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

For reasons I won't go into, I can't use xsl:include in my production environment so when I write XSLT which uses xsl:includes I preprocess the XSLT files to simulate this instruction and produce a complete single XSLT file.

This is my pseudo xsl:include simulator.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
   
    <xsl:template match="xsl:include">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works pretty well, BUT it irritatingly reformats the code, in a bad way, so code like this:

```
   <xsl:map-entry
      key="'meWatchPushDate'"
      select="
      function($tx) 
      { 
         (  $tx/tx_starttimepoint/ESP_TIMEINSTANT/xs:dateTime(@full) 
               => mgx:datetime_to_pushdateformat(),
            ''
         )[1]
      }"/>
```

gets mashed into

```
   <xsl:map-entry key="'meWatchPushDate'"
                   select="                   function($tx)                    {                       (  $tx/tx_starttimepoint/ESP_TIMEINSTANT/xs:dateTime(@full)                             =&gt; mgx:datetime_to_pushdateformat(),                         ''                      )[1]                   }"/>
```

which is a tad irritating.

(actually this is a duplicate! - [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317052/daniel-haley))

I'm happy for any solution to include tips of formatting XPath expressions so that they don't get mashed.

(Its ironic that xslt is actually not capable of mapping itself without reformatting itself.)

Comment: I believe this is happening because of attribute value normalization. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63142223/317052) for more details and a possible workaround.

Comment: I don't have a suggestion for your attribute normalization problem but I wonder what `xsl:stylesheet version="3.1"` is good for. Any reason to use that version number and put any XSLT 3.0 processor into "forwards compatible processing mode" https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#forwards?

Comment: does it not exist? I thought it did and I was just being 'current'

Comment: @DanielHaley - thats the old post, let me at least put a link on the question

Comment: @MartinHonnen - ah...I changed it to 3.0 and it broke, I use "as='...'" in apply-templates sometimes

Comment: Is `apply-templates as=".."` your own invention/extension that is defined/implemented somewhere? I can't find it in the existing 3.0 standard nor in the current 4.0 draft https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xslt-40/Overview.html#applying-templates.

Comment: Also, maybe you should go into the details about why you can't use xsl:include in your production environment. If you're using XSLT 3.0, there might be options so you don't have to preprocess the XSLT. (If the reason is you need to do conditional imports, you can do that now. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103243/317052) for an example.)

Comment: I cant use xslt include, because I can only supply 1 xslt 'file' to the production system, so there is nothing that can be included

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates mode="makeToggleTifRowFromTransmission"
                                  select="transmissions/ES_TRANSMISSION"
                                  as="element(mgx:ToggleTifRow)*">

in 3.0 this will error out with
Compilation error @as not allowed on <xsl:apply-templates/>

Comment: @MartinHonnen see above

Comment: Yes, but my point is that using `version="3.1"` with existing "3.0" implementations achieves nothing but ignore the wrong `as` attribute, as well as cover/swallow other potential errors. But in the end it is your code and your decision...

Comment: I don't understand, Saxon's behaviour changes when the version number changes, so I assume Saxon understands 3.1 and allows me to do things that I want to do (e..g. the "as" thing).
Why would I set it to 3.0 when I can set it to 3.1? am I missing something?...are you saying 3.1 doesnt "exist" in some sense, and saxon is going into some weird future mode?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to do this in XSLT.

I'll probably try to do it in another language, my transforms are trivial (as you can see in the OP).

I'll post my results here, so at least people will know if this is an inherent/endemic issue with XML transforms, or an XSLT issue.